# How do I incorporate bucket endpoint with bucket name in the S3_PING discovery protocol?

Tags: jboss, jgroups

I'm getting the following error when I try to use bucket_name + bucket endpoint on S3_PING discovery protocol

MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.jgroups.channel.cluster: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.jgroups.channel.cluster: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
        at org.infinispan.server.jgroups.spi.service.ChannelBuilder.start(ChannelBuilder.java:79)

Answer (score 0):

After adding the hostname property to the S3_PING protocol I was able to get the cluster upload a file to the s3 bucket:

```
<protocol type="S3_PING">
        <property name="host">
            hostname
        </property>
        <property name="access_key">
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        </property>
        <property name="secret_access_key">
            xxxxxxxxxxxx
        </property>
        <property name="location">
            S3_BUCKET_NAME
         </property>
        <property name="timeout">
            60000
        </property>
    </protocol>
```